# How to retrieve the insert ID when inserting data via Connection::insert()?

Tags: cakephp, datasource, cakephp-3.0

I want use connectionManager in piece of my project.

how can I access insert id by using connectionManager::insert

for example:

```
 $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
 $connection->insert('cities', 
    [
       'name' => $city,
       'country' => $country_code,
    ]
 );
```

Comment: 'cities' not has any model in my project and I don't neet to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do that, this will "just work" whether you create an explicit cities table class or not:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$table = TableRegistry::get('cities');
$entity = $table->newEntity(
    [
       'name' => $city,
       'country' => $country_code,
    ]
);
$table->save($entity);
$cityId = $entity->id;
```

### But how?

Calling insert, returns a statement object:

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$statement = $connection->insert('cities', 
    [
       'name' => $city,
       'country' => $country_code,
    ]
 );
```

Which can then be used to find the last insert id:

```
$cityId = $statement->lastInsertId('cities');
```

This is one of the things you don't need to worry about using the ORM as designed as the save method [takes care of that automatically](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.0/src/ORM/Table.php#L1528-L1546).